# "It looked not (very) large." is correct with "very" but incorrect without, right?

Tags: negation, adverbial-phrases, modifiers, adjective-phrases

The aim of this question is to understand the structure "not + modifier + adjective/adverb" better.
Does it always sound natural?
If not, then when can we use it and when not?

---

the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 809:
**(1a)** *It somehow sounded* [ *not **quite** right* ].
**(2a)** *I find his story* [ *not **wholly** convincing* ].
**(3a)** *He spoke* [ *not **very** confidently* ].

the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 807:
**(4a)** *He seemed* [ *not **entirely** honest* ].

my variants without the modifiers (the words in bold):
**(1b)** *It somehow sounded not right*.
**(2b)** *I find his story not convincing*.
**(3b)** *He spoke not confidently*.
**(4b)** *He seemed not honest*.

Am I right that (1b)-(4b) are incorrect?

---

the textbook "the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language", page 809:
**(5a)** *a not large house* — incorrect
**(6a)** *It looked not large*. — incorrect

my variants with "*very*":
**(5b)** *a not **very** large house*
**(6b)** *It looked not **very** large*.

Am I right that (5b) & (6b) are correct?

Comment: As a non-native speaker, you should probably avoid ***all*** of these examples. Things like ***a not large house*** and ***It looked not large*** are perfectly valid *syntactically* - they're just *totally non-idiomatic*. There are very few contexts where native Anglophones would use any of your cited examples. Although you'll be able to find examples of the "marked" usage *He seemed not entirely honest* (usually as an "affected" understatement), you'd be much safer sticking to the standard "do-support" mechanism for negation: ***He didn't seem entirely honest.***

Comment: Simple proofreading questions are off-topic here. This is *not* a simple proofreading question—but it could still get better answers if you elaborated about *why* you're asking and about your thoughts. Because yes, you're right, you can't delete the modifiers without changing the syntax (and the meaning)! But "yeah, you're right" isn't much of an answer. Please edit to tell more.

Comment: Also note: it's not so much that any of these are *wrong*, but just outside of common idiomatic usage. Many of your modifications "sound Shakespearean"; you find constructions like "He looks not well" in older periods. The meaning would be clear today, but it would sound odd. Meanwhile, even some of the Cambridge examples border on sounding odd today. (And some Shakespearean constructions follow their pattern—"He loved not too wisely.") They could all be rewritten to place the negation before the verb.

Comment: Jeez, who's going around down-voting? The description of a downvote is "This question does not show any research effort;"—it definitely does and even cites a page number—"it is unclear or not useful." While I would appreciate more elaboration, it's not *unclear*.

Comment: @AndyBonner 1) It seems to me the structure { not + ... + adjective/adverb } makes the language more beautiful and interesting because it steps aside from the standard introduction of the auxiliary "do". 2) Does my variant "_It looked not very large._" sound natural or odd? Thanks. 3) I edited the post a little bit by adding some text at the beginning.

Comment: Heh, true, but it can be dangerous to "step aside from the standard." Poetic and eloquent writing often goes outside standard practice, but it's easy to accidentally become "confusing or awkward" instead of "beautiful and interesting."

Answer (score 1):

The most likely thing a native speaker would do is this:

It somehow sounded [ not quite right ]would be expressed as:

- It somehow didn't sound quite right.

  And I find his story [ not wholly convincing ]. would be expressed as:
- And I didn't find his story wholly convincing.

And: the house looked **quite** small. Your examples in 5 and 6 are not right.
**very** would become **quite** in native **speech**...

In writing, the most likely can be this:
The house, not very large, stood on the hill like a large pumpkin.

Not very large, the house stood on the hill like a pumpkin.

The not-so-large house was really quite ugly.

If you **prepend an adjectival phrase to a noun**, it is usually hyphenated, mostly never used in speech and is used for a stylistic reason:

- The man's not-so-lugubrious tone was, overall, most annoying.

There in fact writer may mean the man's attempt at humour.

Comment: You said: "very" would become "quite" in native speech. Did I understand you correctly that "_a not **very** large house_" and "_It looked not **very** large_" are both incorrect but "_a not **quite** large house_" and "_It looked not **quite** large_" are both correct?

Comment: @Loviii We negativize the verb. It didn't look very large. It looked quite small/didn't look very largel. It wasn't very large. I've explained how a prepended phrase would look. Generally:  quite large, quite small. quite usually goes with declaratives. I wish you wouldn't keep changing the question. It makes giving an answer very hard. And not quite is a no-go except in cases like: He didn't quite get the point.

Comment: Dialogue: It looked....not very large.

Comment: @Loviii Note: as a positive, "very X" and "quite X" are pretty similar. But as a negative, "not very X" has a different meaning from "not quite X." If I'm "not quite drunk," then I'm just tipsy; not actually drunk yet, but almost. If I'm "not very drunk," then I *am* drunk, but not very much. (Note, anyone who makes either of these points strongly might not actually be the best judge of their own sobriety.)

Comment: @Lambie The question is about the structure "not + modifier + adjective/adverb". The question is not about how to replace this structure with some other sentences (e.g. with the sentences which have negation via auxiliaries).

Comment: @Lambie Why is "_It looked not quite/very large_" not correct whereas "_It somehow sounded not quite right_" and "_He seemed not entirely honest_" are correct? They all have the same structure. Then why are these sentences different in terms of their correctness?

Comment: I have told you what is no-go. I have also told you what native speakers would probably say. I even pointed out **a dialogue or spoken English variation** (see above in the comments) as in: It somehow sounded...not quite right. He seemed...not entirely honest. **Those are said as afterthoughts in connected speech**.  Because **otherwise** a native speaker would not use those and would negativize the sentence.

Comment: And also: not quite large is not idiomatic except in **unusual collocations** such as: The house looked...not quite large really, but largish.

Comment: @Lambie I looked "no-go" up in dictionaries but didn't quite understand it. Could you tell me please what you mean by "no-go"?

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary: no-go, not acceptable. It has other meanings, too.

Comment: @Lambie You said "_a not very large house_" is incorrect. I found some phrases with "_a not very_" in Collins' dictionary: [( i ):](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/edifying) "_It all brought back memories of **a not very** edifying past_"; [( ii ):](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/no-risk) "_We prefer to play on **a not very** good pitch with no risk for the players_"; [( iii ):](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/overdramatise) "_I had overdramatised **a not very** dramatic situation, it's true_". Do they all seem incorrect to you?

Comment: Read what I said about hyphenated phrases. I gave two examples. And your variants 5 and 6 have zero context. I believe I have given enough here. Cheers. Those links don't work.

Comment: And: We prefer to play on a not very good pitch with no risk for the players.
Times, Sunday Times (2006)
Has a HUGE mistake in logic. It got botted up there and no one caught it.